"Error Encountered with npx Command: Node.js Path Issue Preventing React App Creation"
I'm trying to check the version of npx by running the command npx -v in the command prompt. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. Here is the error message:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"'
is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Because of this, I'm unable to create a new React app using npx create-react-app my-app.
I've already tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Reinstalled Node.js and npm.
Checked that the Node.js installation path is correctly added to the system's PATH variable.
Ran the command prompt as an administrator.
None of these steps have resolved the issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution? What else can I do to fix this path issue with Node.js and npm?
System Information:
OS: Window
Node.js Version: v20.13.1
npm Version: 10.5.2
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
